# Scripting problems in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Player item does not exist in Move script]

I'm a Unity beginner.
I have a problem with my script: in the picture above, Player item does not exist in Move script.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform player;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transform.Translate(x * speed * Time.deltaTime, y * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        Vector2 v2 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - player.position;
        player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(v2.y, v2.x) * Mathf.Red2Deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Unity, operating system and IDE are you using? Also, have you made sure that you've saved the script since adding `public Transform player;`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you right, but as this script is the script that belongs to the Player Gameobject, you don't need to specify "public Transform player".
The Gameobject class inherits from the Transform class, so it should work if you try:

```
Vector2 v2 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(v2.y, v2.x) * Mathf.Red2Deg);
```

Maybe to make it more clear:
You don't need to have Player as an "item" that you pull into the according field in the inspector as it was the case if you relate to a gameobject which does not contain the "Move" script.
So, if you attach a script to a gameobject (in this case you attach the script to "Player"), then any methods you script, are directly affecting the gameobject the script belongs to.
E.g. try the following:

```
void Update() {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

You will see that the circle, which forms your player, will destroy itself when you hit the space bar. The parameter "gameObject" refers to the gameobject the script belongs to.

I hope that helps you to understand that you don't need to specify an extra GameObject that needs to be linked to the script, as long as the Gameobject you want to manipulate contains this script.